# Exporting Markdown to PDF in Obsidian.md: How do I retain highlight colors in PDF?

Tags: css, pdf, markdown

I'm using `Obsidian.md` and have created a css snippet that lets me utilize a combination of `**bold**`, `*italics*` and `==highlights==` to create three different colors; see image.

**Markdown Colors**

[image: Markdown Colors]

However, these colors are lost when I export the file to PDF, since the snippet doesn't govern that; I think it has to do with css printing, but I'm not sure. In the PDF it would look like this:
[image: PDF Colors]

Would anyone here be able to help me figure out, how to have the colors appear the same in markdown and in PDF?

I'll share a part of the snippet below. This is for the red color, which is created by combining italics/asterisks and highlights/equal signs:

```css
:root
{
  --highlight-lred: #f0a6a6;
  --highlight-dred: #c08484;

}

/* Red Highlight */


span.cm-em.cm-highlight {
    font-style: unset !important; 
    background-color: var(--highlight-red);
    color: #222;
}

body > .app-container div.markdown-preview-view em > mark {
    /*font-style: initial !important; */
    background-color: var(--highlight-red);
    color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use media query for this:

**Ex:**

```css
@media print {

  span.cm-em.cm-highlight {
    background-color: var(--highlight-red);
    color: #222;
  }

  body>.app-container div.markdown-preview-view em>mark {
    background-color: var(--highlight-red);
    color: #222;
  }

}
```

Comment: That's pretty much how I eventually solved it, except that it seems I don't need the `@media print`, but that might be a specific Obsidian thing, I'm not sure. Thanks for the help :)